How can I plot a linear mixed model in R with a regression line and confidence interval that match the data?
I am trying to plot this model: m1 <- lmer(tarsus.yc ~ BMR + MMR + Msum + (1|box), data = p2).
I want one plot per predictor and use the parameter estimates from the full model for the regression line. So, first I mean-centered the predictors that I do not want in the plot.
Then, when I use the estimates from the summary table, my regression line does not match my data.
For the confidence interval, I tried to use the predict function but it is not a smooth polygon and that is not what I am trying to do.
Maybe I am not doing it correctly or my code is wrong.
Here is what I did so far:
#Full model
m1 <- lmer(tarsus.yc ~ BMR.mc + MMR + Msum.mc + (1|box), data = p2)
summary(m1)
cf <- coef(summary(m1))

#Predicted values
newMMR <- seq(min(p2$MMR), max(p2$MMR), length.out = 42)
y_hat <- cf[1] + cf[4]*newMMR
`
df <- data.frame(MMR = p2$MMR, tarsus = p2$tarsus.yc, y_hat = y_hat, newMMR = newMMR)

ggplot(df, aes(x = MMR, y = tarsus)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(x = newMMR, y = y_hat)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 28) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_blank(),   
        axis.line = element_line(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 18),  
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 12), size = 20),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 12), size = 20))+ 
  labs(x = "MMR (W)", y = "Nestling tarsus length (mm)")

Then the plot looks like this.
Also, I tried to use the geom_smooth command in ggplot to create the regression line but then I get the parameter estimates of a simpler model (tarsus.yc ~ MMR) and that is not what I am looking for.
Let me know if you need more information and thank you for your time!
